# I can't see change on Android Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, view, android-coordinatorlayout

I can't see correct data on my Coordinator Layout: I mean, my layout seems correctly set and my java class is correct too.
But when I launch my application I don't see error but my activity have TextView, Image and WebView not initialized with passed data.
I tried to inflate all content with traditional

(TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_id) and with butterknife.ButterKnife library, same result.

Here my activity

```
public class EventDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {


private long eventID;
private String eventTitle;
private String eventDesc;
private String eventDate;
private String eventTime;
private String eventImageUrl;
private String eventAddress;
private Double lat;
private Double lng;
private int maxBookings;

@InjectView(R.id.event_title) TextView eventTitleTv;
@InjectView(R.id.event_address) TextView eventAddressTv;
@InjectView(R.id.event_start_date) TextView eventDateTv;
@InjectView(R.id.event_start_time) TextView eventTimeTv;
@InjectView(R.id.event_image) ImageView imageEventView;
@InjectView(R.id.map_address) TextView evetMapAddress;
@InjectView(R.id.event_desc) WebView mWebView;
@InjectView(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;
@InjectView(R.id.collapsing_toolbar) CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
@InjectView(R.id.btnJoin) AppCompatButton btnJoin;
@InjectView(R.id.open_map_button) FloatingActionButton openMapButton;


private MapFragment googleMap;
private GoogleMap map;
private Event event;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initActivityTransitions();
    setContentView(R.layout.event_details_activity);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    btnJoin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialogPlus();
        }
    });

    openMapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openMapDetail();
        }
    });

    try {

        inizializeToolbar();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            event = extras == null ? null : (Event) extras.getSerializable(Const.EVENT_OBJECT);

        } else {
            event = (Event) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(Const.EVENT_OBJECT);
        }

        eventTitle = event.getEventName();
        eventDesc = event.getEventContent();
        eventDate = event.getEventStartDate();
        eventTime = event.getEventStartTime();
        eventImageUrl = event.getEventImageUrl();
        lat = event.getLocationLatitude();
        lng = event.getLocationLongitude();
        eventAddress = event.getLocationAddress();
        eventID =  event.getEventId();

        maxBookings = 10;
        Log.d("EVENT", "__event title " + eventTitle);
        Log.d("EVENT", "__event eventDesc " + eventDesc);
        Log.d("EVENT", "__event eventDate " + eventDate);
        Log.d("EVENT", "__event eventTime " + eventTime);
        Log.d("EVENT", "__event eventImageUrl " + eventImageUrl);
        Log.d("EVENT", "__event lat " + lat);
        Log.d("EVENT", "__event lng " + lng);
        Log.d("EVENT", "__event eventAddress " + eventAddress);
        Log.d("EVENT", "__event eventTitle " + eventTitle);
        Log.d("EVENT", "__event evv name " + event.getEventName());

        initializeMap();
        loadImage();
        loadTextViews();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

private void initActivityTransitions() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Slide transition = new Slide();
        transition.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(transition);
        getWindow().setReturnTransition(transition);
    }
}

private void inizializeToolbar() {

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(eventTitle);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void loadTextViews(){

    eventTitleTv.setText("TITOLO DELL'EVENTO");
    eventAddressTv.setText(eventAddress);
    evetMapAddress.setText(eventAddress + " -> ");
    setEventDesc();
    eventDateTv.setText(Utils.getDateFromString(eventDate));
    eventTimeTv.setText(Utils.getTimeFromString(eventTime));

}


private void loadImage(){

    final ProgressBar progressView = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loader);
    progressView.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(eventImageUrl)
            .fit().centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.event_placeholder_grey_2)
            .into(imageEventView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    progressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    progressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            });

}

private void showDialogPlus() {

    Holder holder = new ViewHolder(R.layout.event_prenotation);

    OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogPlus dialog, View view) {

            Spinner mySpinner=(Spinner) dialog.getHolderView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);

            String bookValue = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();;
            int numberPerson = Integer.parseInt(bookValue);
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnJoin:

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConfirmPrenotationActivity.class);
                    Bundle bun = new Bundle();
                    bun.putInt(Const.NUMBER_PRENOT, numberPerson);
                    bun.putString(Const.EVENT_TITLE, eventTitle);
                    bun.putLong(Const.EVENT_ID, eventID);
                    bun.putSerializable(Const.EVENT_OBJECT, event);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.putExtras(bun);
                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                    break;

            }
            //dialog.dismiss();
        }
    };

    OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(DialogPlus dialog, Object item, View view, int position) {
            //TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            //String clickedAppName = textView.getText().toString();
            //        dialog.dismiss();
            //        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, clickedAppName + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    OnDismissListener dismissListener = new OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogPlus dialog) {
            //        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "dismiss listener invoked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    OnCancelListener cancelListener = new OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogPlus dialog) {
            //        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "cancel listener invoked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    final DialogPlus dialog = DialogPlus.newDialog(this)
            .setContentHolder(holder)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
            .setOnClickListener(clickListener)
            .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override public void onItemClick(DialogPlus dialog, Object item, View view, int position) {
                    Log.d("DialogPlus", "onItemClick() called with: " + "item = [" +
                            item + "], position = [" + position + "]");
                }
            })
            .setOnDismissListener(dismissListener)
                    //.setExpanded(expanded)
                    //.setContentWidth(800)
            .setContentHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            .setOnCancelListener(cancelListener)
            .setOverlayBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent)
                    //.setContentBackgroundResource(R.drawable.corner_background)
                    //.setOutMostMargin(0, 100, 0, 0)
            .create();



    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    initializeSpinner(spinner);


    dialog.show();

}


public void initializeSpinner(Spinner spin){

    ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=1; i<= maxBookings; i++){
        options.add(""+i);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_style, options) {

        public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            ((TextView) v).setTextSize(18);

            return v;

        }

        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView,parent);

            //((TextView) v).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            return v;

        }

    };

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(adapter);
}


public void setEventDesc(){

    mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<html><body>");
    sb.append("<p align=\"justify\">");
    sb.append(eventDesc);
    sb.append("</p>");
    sb.append("</body></html>");

    //mWebView.loadData(sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
    mWebView.loadData(sb.toString(), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void initializeMap() {

    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        googleMap.getMapAsync(this);

    }

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_event_details, menu);

    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.share_button:

            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getEventInfoToShare());
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share link using"));

            return true;

        default:
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }


}

private String getEventInfoToShare(){

    StringBuilder infoEvent = new StringBuilder();
    infoEvent.append("Ciao, vorrei consigliarti un evento :-)");
    infoEvent.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    infoEvent.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    infoEvent.append(eventTitle);
    infoEvent.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    infoEvent.append(eventAddress);
    infoEvent.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    infoEvent.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    infoEvent.append(eventDesc.substring(0, Math.min(eventDesc.length(), 200)));
    infoEvent.append("...continua");
    infoEvent.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    infoEvent.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    infoEvent.append("Visita -> www.dayroma.it");


    return infoEvent.toString();
}




@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();

}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    map = googleMap;
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    map.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 15.0f));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
            .title(eventTitle));
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            openMapDetail();
            return true;
        }
    });

}

public void openMapDetail(){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsDetailActivity.class);
    Bundle bun = new Bundle();
    bun.putDouble(Const.EVENT_LAT, lat);
    bun.putDouble(Const.EVENT_LONG, lng);
    bun.putString(Const.EVENT_TITLE, eventTitle);
    bun.putString(Const.EVENT_ADDRESS, eventAddress);
    bun.putString(Const.EVENT_IMG_LINK, eventImageUrl);
    bun.putSerializable(Const.EVENT_OBJECT, event);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.putExtras(bun);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
}


@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

    openMapDetail();

}
```

}

And here the layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_event_detail_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/ColorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <util.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/event_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/image_event_detail_height"
            android:maxHeight="@dimen/image_event_detail_height"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >


        <!--<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >


            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loader"
                android:layout_width="75dip"
                android:layout_height="75dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"

                />

        </RelativeLayout>-->


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/google_cards_background_bottom"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- Titolo Evento -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/event_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Eat at Joe"
                android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimary"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />


            <!-- indirizzo -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/event_address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="data inizio"

                android:textColor="@color/material_grey_500"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_position_black_18dp"
                android:drawablePadding="2dip"
                />



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <!-- data inizio evento-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/event_start_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:text="data inizio"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_grey_500"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/calendar_black_18dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dip"

                    />

                <!-- ora inizio evento-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/event_start_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:text="data inizio"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_grey_500"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/clock_18dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dip"

                    />



            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>


        </LinearLayout>




        <!-- DETTAGLI -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape"
            >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/event_detail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Dettagli"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:gravity="center"

                />


            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"    >
                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/event_desc"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                    />
            </ScrollView>



        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- FINE DETTAGLI -->


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:foreground="@color/dark_trasparent"

                >
                <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/map_height"
                    map:cameraTargetLat="41.890122"
                    map:cameraTargetLng="12.494248"
                    map:cameraTilt="30"
                    map:cameraZoom="15"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <!-- Maps Address -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/map_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:text="via Cristoforo Colombo 24"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_position_white_18dp"
                    />


            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>



</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/open_map_button"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:tint="@color/cpb_grey"
    android:src="@drawable/navigation_black_24dp"
    style="@style/floatButtonStyle"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnJoin"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_red"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fixed_bottom_button_height"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/join_event"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

It seems a simple problem but I've never had like this before: here a screenshot of my activity, it should be visualize an event details.

[Screenshot Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N01TW.png)

This activity is opened when a user click on an event and is fill with event data: data are correctly set because I can see all from log.

I really don't understand why TextViews, ImageView and other element are not filled with data.

Thank you for help

Comment: I guess you are having an exception in your catch block?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see **any closing tag for Coordinator layout** in your xml file. If you haven't missed it in question then probably that is the reason for this strange behavior.

Add this at the end of your xml code and things should work better.

```
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Or, if that is just the mistake in question then please update your question. Whatever it is do let me know.

Comment: Sorry I pasted wrong code at the end: closing tag for Coordinator layout is present. It's making me crazy this strange layout behavior